# R - Occurence by variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset called restrictions and I know if people can do actions (eat with a fork, come out of bed...).

Each number represents with which level of difficulty each individual can do an action (1: No difficulty, 2: Some difficulties, 3: High difficulties, 4: Cannot do the action at all)

I am mostly interested in level 4.

The dataset looks like this (with many more variables)

```
> head(restrictions)
  RATOI_I RAHAB_I RANOU_I RAELI_I RAACH_I RAREP_I RAMEN_I RAADM_I RAMED_I RADPI_I RADPE_I RABUS_I  
1       4       4       1       1       4       4       4       4       1       1       4       4              
2       4       3       3       1       4       4       4       4       4       2       4       4
```

I would like to know how many people are level 4 in RATOI_I (I can do that) and for these people level 4 in RATOI_I, how many are level 4 in RAHAB_I and each variable.

I looked at the function sapply() but I am completely lost, I do not know how to use it and with which function.
Or must I maybe use the group_by() function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, what is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `sum` using `restrictions==4` to count the number equal 4 per column.

```
apply(restrictions==4, 2, sum)
#colSums(restrictions==4) #Alternative
#RATOI_I RAHAB_I RANOU_I RAELI_I RAACH_I RAREP_I RAMEN_I RAADM_I RAMED_I RADPI_I RADPE_I RABUS_I 
#      2       1       0       0       2       2       2       2       1       0       2       2
```

Or only for those having `restrictions$RATOI_I==4` (Thanks to @Daniel-o for pointing on this):

```
apply(restrictions[restrictions$RATOI_I==4]==4, 2, sum)
#colSums(restrictions[restrictions$RATOI_I==4]==4)
#RATOI_I RAHAB_I RANOU_I RAELI_I RAACH_I RAREP_I RAMEN_I RAADM_I RAMED_I RADPI_I RADPE_I RABUS_I 
#      2       1       0       0       2       2       2       2       1       0       2       2
```

Comment: From the wording, OP might be asking for `apply(restrictions[restrictions$RATOI_I==4]==4, 2, sum)`

Comment: @DanielO Oh yes! I now think so to. -> make an update.

Comment: Thank you Daniel O and GKi! However, I do not understand the purpose of the 2. What it is here for?

Comment: It's to tell `apply` to go over columns. (With 1 it will go over rows.)

Answer (score 0):

we can also do by base packages:

```
df[df<4]<-0
df[df==4]<-1
colSums(df)

>RATOI_I RAHAB_I RANOU_I RAELI_I RAACH_I RAREP_I RAMEN_I RAADM_I RAMED_I RADPI_I RADPE_I RABUS_I 
      2       1       0       0       2       2       2       2       1       0       2       2
```